# Time to wait before submitting again site to DMOZ.org

Tags: seo, dmoz

Most sites I have done, got listed in DMOZ. It has always being a very frustrating process that required waiting for months.
For some of these sites I had also to resubmit them again in order to see them listed.

My question is: in case site A does not get listed in DMOZ after the 1st submission, do you know how long should I wait before submitting site A again? I'm supposing DMOZ does not enjoy receiveing the same site submitted each day by the same person.

Maybe some of you was/is a DMOZ editor and knows the answer.

Thanks

---

UPDATE: Thanks to *danlefree*, I should have explained in my question that I know on DMOZ guideline they say to [submit site only once](http://www.dmoz.org/add.html).

But by following slavishly DMOZ guideline: **a site that was not included on 1st attempt should not be submitted again for the rest of your life.**

I think it's common sense to try to understand what was wrong with the not included site, try to fix it and **after some time** try to submit the site again to DMOZ for inclusion.

My question is more about what you percieve to be the right time to wait before submitting again a site to DMOZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible that there is simply no editor for your category. Or, they may have rejected your site for some reason. Either way, I'd give it another try after 4-6 months if it's not there and then just forget about it. It will either get approved or not, but a single link isn't worth spending a lot of time on, even if it is DMOZ. There are other ways to get links.

Comment: Thanks, your way of thinking at links in terms of time spent to insert them is always something I should think more about. Thanks, again for riminding me.

Answer (score 8):

As a former editor I know that in some categories without editors, the list of sites just grows. When I first started on my specific category, nothing had changed for more than a year. Technically, there is no definite answer. It is possible that even after months, still nobody has added/rejected your site. Getting information on why your site was rejected is next to impossible.

Answer (score 3):

> An ODP editor will review your
>   submission to determine whether to
>   include it in the directory. Depending
>   on factors such as the volume of
>   submissions to the particular
>   category, it may take several weeks or
>   more before your submission is
>   reviewed. Please only submit a URL to
>   the Open Directory once.

[DMOZ Submission Guidelines](http://www.dmoz.org/add.html)

> I should have explained in my question
>   that I know on DMOZ guideline they say
>   to submit site only once.

Unfortunately, there are very few (if any) guarantees that you will be able to address a declined submission at DMOZ no matter how many times you resubmit, so my best advice would be to move on to other venues for advertising rather than risk evoking the ire of DMOZ's editor(s) for the category you're submitting to (a second and final request sent after 6 months seems reasonable, though).

Comment: Thanks for the link anyway, I updated my question, sorry for not explaining it before.

Answer (score 2):

My advice: **Become an editor**. For most categories, you have better odds of becoming an editor than you do getting your website accepted.

I'm an editor of my own niche category and there were 600 websites in queue when I first logged in. Most of these websites had been in queue for *years*. The second I was accepted, I submitted my website (and linked it to my editor profile to comply with the honesty guidelines) and submitted some other key websites in my niche to make a good contribution that wasn't purely self-servicing.

Comment: I asked to become an editor for a niche with only 5 sites listed, they incerdibly replied me after 5 months saying they rejected my request without giving any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to wait at least two months (if not three) to ensure your site has been rejected.

If your site was not listed then obviously you need to look at the reasons why. Make some changes to the site if necessary, then resubmit.