# Is it really worth submitting to DMOZ anymore?

Tags: seo, bing, dmoz

This question stems from [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/time-to-wait-before-submitting-again-site-to-dmoz-org). This guy sounds like he's getting a bit annoyed with DMOZ, but I was wondering if it's even worth submitting there nowadays. Does anyone still use it as a search engine?

I would say that time would be better spent on getting your SEO on to get higher in Google and (possibly) Yahoo/Bing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DMOZ isn't what is was once paraded to be. Frankly, it's a joke of a project, but there's still SEO utility to be drawn from it.

**I highly recommend applying to be an editor of your website's niche.** I became the editor of my niche and there were about 600 websites in queue, many of them in queue for years. I'm confident that for most people, you'll become an editor faster than you website will roll down queue.

DMOZ is still a solid backlink. It's worth it because it shouldn't take you long to both submit your site and submit an editor application if you're so inclined. But it's **not** worth it to then check DMOZ every day and pine over admission to the DMOZ elite. Submit and forget.

Comment: Does dmoz policy allow approving your own site?

Comment: Yes, but you must list in your profile all sites in which you are related, and obviously your website must add value to the domain you approve it in.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, submitting to DMoz works less than 1 in 10 times, but that's still better than most link building activities.

Comment: I do agree. If the submission form itself works technically (which is 1 in 10 times, to me), the approval rate is rather low for me, too. Maybe the things I try to submit are not valuable enough to the DMOZ editors?

Comment: I agree. The editors are often very politicized, protecting their own interests (sites and therefore revenue streams). Getting listed is a complete lottery in many categories. I'm surprised that Google still considers it worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Why? Because it's simple to do and it can be a relatively high quality link. Will it deliver a lot of traffic? probably not. But since it takes only a minute to do and will get you into Google's directory as well why not do it?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read the article but I'm also getting annoyed with DMOZ. As they look for other ways to earn money, I think the quality of the index is likely to go down.

However, I still submit my sites to them. A link is a link. I just won't do anything special and am certainly not going to pay them.

Answer (score 0):

Dmoz added my site a month ago, they spent a total of 14 seconds looking at it( i have analytics) so do they really care what actually gets on there
Dmoz has not sffected my serp position or my PR in any way, i only have 20 backlinks so if DMOZ was worth anything i would have moved up the ranks for my choosen kerywords