# After Google's penguin 2.0, is a DMOZ listing still effective?

Tags: google, pagerank, ranking, google-penguin-algorithm, dmoz

Please look at the following questions in which answers say that a listing in [DMOZ](http://dmoz.org) is useful for rank:

- [Does an entry in DMOZ significantly help the ranking of a web site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/634/does-an-entry-in-dmoz-significantly-help-the-ranking-of-a-web-site)
- [Is it really worth submitting to DMOZ anymore?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6968/is-it-really-worth-submitting-to-dmoz-anymore)

**Now** with Google's Penguin 2.0 algorithm update, is being listed in [DMOZ](http://dmoz.org) worth it for a website's rank?

Comment: What's up?!!! Any question regarding Google's penguin 2.0 is going to be closed?! It is new algorithm and it affects many websites' traffic over the web so, I think that, it is suitable to ask about it in comparison with older questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DMOZ listing won't hurt your site for the Penguin algorithm.

- The links are editorially reviewed.
- The open directory project doesn't accept any sort of payment for links.
- You can suggest your own anchor text, but anchor text is rarely keyword rich (if it is, I suggest submitting and update to change it to your brand name).
- Tons of good sites have dmoz listings.  If Google were to penalize for a dmoz listing, it would hurt far too many good sites too.

I've seen some [conjecture that all the sites that duplicate the dmoz directory (many of which are very low quality) might hurt in some cases](http://forums.seochat.com/google-optimization-7/dmoz-directory-panda-penguin-problem-460263.html).   The responses on that thread seem to lean towards  "it can't hurt".

DMOZ is certainly not the powerhouse that it once was for powering rankings (as the questions you link to show).  But, DMOZ is not any more risky now than it was before Penguin.